# How is the record count of a multipoint shapefile dbf file determined?

Tags: shapefile, dbf, create, multipoint

I'm writing a program to create a multipoint shapefile (.shp .shx .dbf), and I'm not sure how the format of the .dbf file should look. The .dbf starts off with a record header, followed by field subrecord structures, which are then followed by the actual records. The records start with a deletion flag followed by data.

With the consideration that this is a multipoint shapefile, how would the records be written? Is each point in the multipoint file a record or are all of the points considered to be one record?

Answer (score 6):

All the points in a multipoint are one record, that is what makes it a multipoint.

**However**,  please don't write another shapefile writer, I can almost guarantee that whatever language you are using there is already a writer that has been tested and checked for interoperability issues.